# Reactjs - Controlling Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, reactjs

Im building a CheckAllBoxes component in Reactjs. I have a list of items

```
fruits = {orange, apple, grape}
```

A general `<SelectBox />` component to display and toggle the HTML checkbox

I need to build a `<Fruits />` component to list all the fruits and each of item has its own `<SelectBox />`

Then I need to build a `<SelectAll />` component which has a `<SelectBox />` and when it is checked, it will toggle all the `<CheckBox />` of `<Fruits />`

If any fruit is unchecked again, then the `<SelectAll />` should be unchecked too.

The result should look something like this:

[image]

How can I get the `<SelectAll />` to control other checkboxes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the quick example on how you could do it:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SelectBox extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      allChecked: false,
      checkedCount: 0,
      options: [
        { value: 'selectAll', text: 'Select All' },
        { value: 'orange', text: 'Orange' },
        { value: 'apple', text: 'Apple' },
        { value: 'grape', text: 'Grape' }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    let clickedValue = e.target.value;

    if (clickedValue === 'selectAll' && this.refs.selectAll.getDOMNode().checked) {
      for (let i = 1; i < this.state.options.length; i++) {
        let value = this.state.options[i].value;
        this.refs[value].getDOMNode().checked = true;
      }
      this.setState({
        checkedCount: this.state.options.length - 1
      });

    } else if (clickedValue === 'selectAll' && !this.refs.selectAll.getDOMNode().checked) {
      for (let i = 1; i < this.state.options.length; i++) {
        let value = this.state.options[i].value;
        this.refs[value].getDOMNode().checked = false;
      }
      this.setState({
        checkedCount: 0
      });
    }

    if (clickedValue !== 'selectAll' && this.refs[clickedValue].getDOMNode().checked) {
      this.setState({
        checkedCount: this.state.checkedCount + 1
      });
    } else if (clickedValue !== 'selectAll' && !this.refs[clickedValue].getDOMNode().checked) {
      this.setState({
        checkedCount: this.state.checkedCount - 1
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Selected boxes: ', this.state.checkedCount);

    const options = this.state.options.map(option => {
      return (
        <input onClick={this.handleClick} type='checkbox' name={option.value} key={option.value}
               value={option.value} ref={option.value} > {option.text} </input>
      );
    });


    return (
      <div className='SelectBox'>
        <form>
          {options}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm sorry for the ES6 example. Will add ES5 example when I find more time, but I think you can get the idea on how to do it. 
Also you definitely want to break this down into 2 components. Then you would just pass your options as props to the Child component.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading [Communication between Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html)

Now in your example you have a communication between two components that don't have a parent-child relationship. In these case you could use a global event system. [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) works great with React.

In your example I would make `FruitStore` with the component `Fruit` listening to store. The `FruitStore` contains a list with all fruits and if they are selected or not. `Fruit` will saves it's content with `setState()`.

`Fruit` passes to it's children their status per props. example: `<CheckBox checked={this.state.fruit.checked} name={this.state.fruit.name}/>`

`Checkbox` should fire when clicked a `FruitAction.checkCheckbox(fruitName)`.

The `FruitStore` will then update the `Fruit` component and so on.

It take some time to get into this unidirectional architecture, but it's worth learning it. Try starting with the [Flux Todo List Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html).

Comment: I think using flux for this is overkill. Also what is the point of having state in the `Fruit` component? If you want to use Flux, then you would have your data in the `FruitStore` and pass it down in props to `Fruit` component...