# Multiple check box options in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new with react and I was having problems with creating check boxes for my application. I was able to setup something that works for only one checkbox option, however the problem I have now is for multiple check box options.

Whenever I click on one checkbox, it automatically selects all other check boxes

Here's the code I'm currently working on.

```
import React, { Component, } from 'react';

export default class Checkbox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();

        let initialState = {
            options: [{ id: 1, answer: 'Apple' }, { id: 2, answer: 'Bananas' }, { id: 3, answer: 'Oranges' }],
            isChecked: false,
        };
        this.state = initialState;
    }

    handleCheckbox() {
        this.setState({
            isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    [...this.state.options].map((e, i) => {
                        return (
                            <label key={e.id}>
                                <input type="checkbox"

                                    disabled={this.props.disabled}

                                    onChange={() => this.handleCheckbox()}

                                    checked={this.state.isChecked}

                                    key={e.id} 
                                />

                                {e.answer} &nbsp;
                          </label>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes because you have declare only one `isCheck`, so it is going to check all

Comment: check this answer it is detailed answer and it contains everything that you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073281/reactjs-controlling-multiple-checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need move `isChecked` inside options:

```
import React, { Component, } from 'react';

export default class Checkbox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();

        let initialState = {
            options: [{ id: 1, answer: 'Apple', isChecked:false }, { id: 2, answer: 'Bananas', isChecked:false }, { id: 3, answer: 'Oranges', isChecked:false }],
        };
        this.state = initialState;
    }

    handleCheckbox(ind) {
        const newOptions = [...this.state.options];

        newOptions[ind].isChecked = !newOptions[ind].isChecked;

        this.setState({
            options: newOptions
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    [...this.state.options].map((e, i) => {
                        return (
                            <label key={e.id}>
                                <input type="checkbox"

                                    disabled={this.props.disabled}

                                    onChange={() => this.handleCheckbox(i)}

                                    checked={e.isChecked}

                                    key={e.id} 
                                />

                                {e.answer} &nbsp;
                          </label>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code as per below:

```
import React, { Component, } from 'react';

export default class Checkbox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();

        let initialState = {
            options: [{ id: 1, answer: 'Apple', isChecked: false }, { id: 2, answer: 'Bananas', isChecked: false }, { id: 3, answer: 'Oranges', isChecked: false }],
       };
        this.state = initialState;
    }

    handleCheckbox(id) {
       const modifiedOptions = [...this.state.options];
       modifiedOptions[id].isChecked = !modifiedOptions[id].isChecked;

    this.setState({
        options: modifiedOptions
    })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    [...this.state.options].map((e, i) => {
                        return (
                            <label key={e.id}>
                                <input type="checkbox"

                                    disabled={this.props.disabled}

                                    onChange={() => this.handleCheckbox(e.id)}

                                    checked={e.isChecked}

                                    key={e.id} 
                                />

                                {e.answer} &nbsp;
                          </label>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )

    }

}
```

Comment: handleCheckbox(id) id will be `undefined`

Comment: `id` not every time equal like index

Comment: In this case it will be equal as we are creating the obejct with different ID's

Comment: Same solution as Vadim's. Thanks!

Comment: I have added this first @GJosh... Anyways your problem solved that is important...